# Supplementary groups' special permissions

Tags: linux, permissions, non-root-user, privileges

After installing [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) I had to add my user to the **wireshark** group to be able to capture packets without root access.

AFAIK Wireshark uses the **libpcap** library which itself uses the [Netlink protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netlink) to get the packets from the kernel infrastructures.And also Netlink requires constructing RAW sockets which needs root access.

My assumptions was :

> 1. Either **wireshark** group has special permissions which makes it (and also each user in that group) able to capture packets without the need of being root or being a sudoer.
> 2. Or it's much simpler. Wireshark just checks whether the current non-root user is in the **wireshark** group and if it is , then it can escalate it's privilege via something like **setuid**.

But the second assumption is false becuse the wireshark hasn't the **setuid** permission.

So what makes each user in the **wireshark** group able to capture packets without root  access ? Or in a more general form : How does a supplementary group get such permissions ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s neither of these options; the permissions are carried by `dumpcap`, which takes care of the packet capture, and has the appropriate capabilities:

```
$ sudo getcap /usr/bin/dumpcap
/usr/bin/dumpcap = cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw+eip
```

It is owned by `root:wireshark`, and executable only by its owner and group, so only usable by users in the `wireshark` group.

See [`/usr/share/wireshark/README.Debian.gz`](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/wireshark/-/blob/debian/master/debian/README.Debian) on your system for details.